# Loading normals without vertex buffer objects does not work OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, vbo, normals

When I load the normal data into the vertex shader using the vertex buffer objects (VBO), then everything works fine:

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO[2]);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalLink, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 3 * 4, 0);
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

But when I try to load normals without VBO:

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(normalLink, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
            false, 0, bufferNormals);
```

Then, the 3D-object ceases to be displayed altogether. I tried a different stride, but it didn't help.

At the same time, vertices and texture coordinates without VBO are loaded into the shader well:

```
GLES30.glVertexAttribPointer(positionLink, 3, GLES30.GL_FLOAT,
            false, 0, bufferVertices);
...
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordinatesLink, 2, GLES30.GL_FLOAT,
            false, 0, bufferTextureCoordinates);

GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLink); 
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordinatesLink);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalLink);
```

**Question**: Can anyone suggest what the problem might be? Thanks for any answer/comment!

Note: To create bufferVertices, bufferTextureCoordinates and bufferNormals variables, I used this method:

```
public static FloatBuffer floatBuffer(float[] data) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(data.length * 4)
                        .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer returnBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    returnBuffer.put(data).position(0);
    return returnBuffer;
}

float[] normals = modelData.getNormals();
FloatBuffer bufferNormals = floatBuffer(normals);
```

Comment: Let me guess: In contrast to the vertices and texture coordinates, the normal vectors are stored in a volatile buffer, because the normal vectors are calculated from the vertices and faces of the mesh.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Hi! Thank You for the prompt! It looks like the problem really was in the original data.